# makefile - commands commence before first target

Tags: makefile

I get this message when starting my makefile, what is the most likely error? It is tab-separated in the beginning of each line.

```
makefile_first30samples_rfam:63: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.

robinm@havpryd:~/Oluf/Project_GCF-2014-313$ head makefile_first30samples_rfam
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_007_GAGTGG.fastq > Cut_merged_007_GAGTGG.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_026_ATGTCA.fastq > Cut_merged_026_ATGTCA.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_030_GTGGCC.fastq > Cut_merged_030_GTGGCC.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_040_CACCGG.fastq > Cut_merged_040_CACCGG.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_086_AGTTCC.fastq > Cut_merged_086_AGTTCC.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_087_CCGTCC.fastq > Cut_merged_087_CCGTCC.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_125_CTTGTA.fastq > Cut_merged_125_CTTGTA.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_197_GCCAAT.fastq > Cut_merged_197_GCCAAT.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_208_CGTACG.fastq > Cut_merged_208_CGTACG.fastq
    #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_226_CAACTA.fastq > Cut_merged_226_CAACTA.fastq
robinm@havpryd:~/Oluf/Project_GCF-2014-313$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Makefile rule must have the form

```
target: ...
        command
        command
```

Looks like yours is missing the target line.

Try something like

```
foo:
        #cutadapt -a TGGAATTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG merged_007_GAGTGG.fastq > Cut_merged_007_GAGTGG.fastq
        ...
```

(with no space before foo: and one tab before each command)

Comment: there was a space in one of the line further down the makefile

Comment: Supplementing @BioMan - the indentation needs to use tabs, not spaces